# Поднять позицию при выдаче из базы

Tags: php, mysql

На странице выводятся товары следующим способом:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$num_rec_per_page=20;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { 
    $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
} else { 
    $page=1; 
} 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM goods ORDER BY (clicks/views)*points DESC LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql); 
?> 
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
    //выводятся товары
}
?>
```

То есть сортируются они при помощи этой математической операции:

```
(clicks/views)*points
```

При обращении к странице может быть указан GET параметр goods_id, где будут перечислены ИД товаров через запятую (?goods_id=1,2,3). Нужно при сортировке товаров поднять эти товары на самый верх, то есть они должны быть первыми в списке. На крайний случай можно, чтобы goods_id содержал только один ИД и товар с таким ИД был первым в сортировке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь есть два подхода: переопределять сортировку или выполнять два запроса. Второй (хотя вам наверняка покажется не так) наиболее предпочтительный: сначала выбираем нужные, потом к ним добавляем остальные (не забывая при этом отфильтровать те, которые уже выбрали). Это будут два довольно простых запроса, которые не будут особо нагружать систему.
Подход с переопределением сортировки заключается в том, чтобы сначала сортировать по соответствию одному из интересующих ID, а во вторую очередь уже по рейтингу показ/клик. Для этого существует конструкция `FIELD()`:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ... ORDER BY FIELD (id, 1, 2, 3), (остальные сортировки)
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно в запросе выводить одни и те же id на самом верху, попробуйте добавить в раздел ORDER BY:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(goods_id, 1, 2, 3) DESC
```

Можно так же комбинировать с другими сортировками